# cmake managed/c++ error LNK2020: unresolved token

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to managed c++, cmake and need some help to get this going.

I am developing two managed/c++ libraries; A, and B, and want the second library
to use the first.

Whatever I try I get:
   MyClassB.cpp.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) MyClassA::.ctor

Example managed code:

```
public ref class MyClassA
{
public:
  MyClassA();
  ~MyClassA();
};
```

Example cmake file, library A

```
string(REPLACE "/RTC1" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /clr /EHa /MDd /GS")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /clr /EHa /MD /GS")
add_library(MyClassA MODULE MyClassA.cpp)
```

Example cmake file, library B

```
Similar to the one for library A, with this addition:
add_library(MyClassA MODULE IMPORTED)
If I uncomment the next line:
#target_link_libraries(MyClassB MyClassA)
I get this error:
Target "KM.Library.Types.Managedd" of type MODULE_LIBRARY may not be linked
into another target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, ...
```

The code above is not the real code, I could not find a way to attach files :-(

Anyway, the task is simple enough I have two managed/c++ libraries and
want to link one to the other. The link step fails.

One other thing if I try dumpbin on library A, the EXPORTS/SYMBOLS section
is empty, is this correct ?

Regards,

Even

Comment: It seems using the /FU flag to the compiler solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems using the /FU flag to the compiler solved the problem

Comment: /FU doesn't make sense without an argument. And is otherwise equivalent to a `#using` directive.